# Blogger manual adsense placement using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, ads, blogger, adsense

I have a blogger website with automatic placement, but I think that's ruined my article. I want to make a custom adsense placement by replacing the text that want to the ads. For example, I want the text "showadshere" to be the ads. I've searched about Javascript DOM but haven't had any success.

I expect that I can replace specific text in the article with ads.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing so.
Your HTML page :

```
<div id="adslot">show ads here</div>
```

Your ad script :

```
var slot = document.querySelector('#adslot');

//check if slot exists on the page
if(slot) {
 //prepare your adsense script / html tags
 var adsense = '<scr'+'ipt async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-yourAdsenseID" crossorigin="anonymous"></scr'+'ipt><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block"  data-ad-client="ca-pub-yourSlotID"  data-ad-slot="'+ slot.id +'"  data-ad-format="auto"   data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins><scr'+'ipt> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</scr'+'ipt>';

//inject adsense node
slot.innerHTML = adsense ;
}
```